# How to bring in a Flow type definition?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a file `types.js` that contains the folliwing:

```
// @flow

export type PropTypes = {
    fields: Object
};
```

I want to make the `fields` type constraint more specific. `fields` corresponds to a property added by a library called `redux-form`.

`redux-form` has a corresponding file under `flow-typed/npm/redux-form_v5.x.x.js` (side question: how does this get added to the filesystem here?).

I presume this contains the type definitions for the library.

How can I bring in the relevant type definition from this into my file `types.js` and apply it to the `fields` property?

I think the type definition should look like this:

```
{ [fieldName: string]: InputProps }
```

I have tried the following to bring in `InputProps`:

- adding `flow-typed/npm/redux-form_v5.x.x.js` to the `.flowconfig` file

...but running yarn flow check says:

> identifier `InputProps`. Could not resolve name

Answer (score 0):

I added the following and it solved my problem:

```
import type { InputProps } from 'redux-form'
```